# The most reliable public folder ever on Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: mac-osx, file-sharing, network-share, public-folders

I need to enforce permissions on a directory, `ugo+rw`. I'd like to assure that files copied in from another directory will have their permissions reset to `ugo+rw`.

I also need to be sure that everyone in my Active Directory domain can access the share with ease (i.e. no login prompts, full read/write on everything recursively, on Windows (smb) or Leopard (afp)).

I'm trying to create an ultra easy to use public folder, however I always seem to run into someone or some machine (i.e. a guest user's machine not on the domain) accessing this folder.

I'm sure there are further details I may be able to provide, but I'm unsure of them. Comment and I'll add them in. Thanks!

Comment: What is serving up this public folder? Samba?

Comment: This would be served by Mac OS X's built-in file sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you serving it from a Mac OS X Server?  I use it to serve a shared folder so that all members of a group have full control of it and everything in it, both from Mac clients connecting over AFP, and linux clients connecting over NFS.  I don't have any SMB clients, so I can't comment on whether it works there.  My hunch would be that it would, because the ACL involved is enforced server-side, and doesn't need to be understood or visible to the client.

1. Make sure you're using an HFS+ volume
2. Use Server Admin.app, and click the File Sharing tab
3. Browse to the shared directory, and click "Share" (if you haven't already)
4. Click the Permissions tab below
5. Add the following ACL:

   <group>;   Allow;   Full Control;   This folder, Child files, Child folders, All descendants